# How to return a string from async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

My method is calling a web service and working asynchronusly.

When getting response, everything works fine and I am getting my response.

The problem starts when I need to return this response.

here is the code of my method:

```
 public async Task<string> sendWithHttpClient(string requestUrl, string json)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri requestUri = new Uri(requestUrl);
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    ...//adding things to header and creating requestcontent
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, requestContent);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {

                        Debug.WriteLine("Success");
                        HttpContent stream = response.Content;
                        //Task<string> data = stream.ReadAsStringAsync();    
                        var data = await stream.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Debug.WriteLine("data len: " + data.Length);
                        Debug.WriteLine("data: " + data);
                        return data;                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Unsuccessful!");
                        Debug.WriteLine("response.StatusCode: " + response.StatusCode);
                        Debug.WriteLine("response.ReasonPhrase: " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                        HttpContent stream = response.Content;    
                        var data = await stream.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        return data;
                     }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ex: " + ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
```

and I am calling it this way:

```
      Task <string> result =  wsUtils.sendWithHttpClient(fullReq, "");           
      Debug.WriteLine("result:: " + result);
```

but when printing result I am seeing something like this: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`

how can I get the result string as I did with *data* inside my method.

Comment: you need to access the `Result` property of your `Task` to get the desired output .

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to do this since you are calling the `async` method **synchronously**:

```
  Task<string> result =  wsUtils.sendWithHttpClient(fullReq, "");           
  Debug.WriteLine("result:: " + result.Result); // Call the Result
```

Think of the `Task<string>` return type as a 'promise' to return a value in the future.

If you called the async method asynchronously then it would be like the following:

```
  string result =  await wsUtils.sendWithHttpClient(fullReq, "");           
  Debug.WriteLine("result:: " + result);
```

Comment: I called it async, and it works, thanks. I will accept it soon.

Comment: The wait is not necessary. The Result property blocks the calling thread until the task finishes. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I used it succesfully.

Comment: As soon as I read the line "Think of the `Task<string> return type as a 'promise' to return a value in the future." I instantly realised my mistake. The `await` was missing. I'm going to mentally bookmark this statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

An asynchronous method returns a *task*, representing a *future value*. In order to get the actual value wrapped in that task, you should `await` it:

```
string result = await wsUtils.sendWithHttpClient(fullReq, "");
Debug.WriteLine("result:: " + result);
```

Note that this will require your calling method to be asynchronous. This is both natural and correct.